# Shortest string within same path (branch)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a tree representation in mysql table based on `id`, `depth`, `parent_id` and `path`. Every *root* record within this table has a depth of `0`, `parent_id != null` and `path` representation based on hex value of ID padded left with `0`.

Every element of the tree is constructed by specifying `depth = parent.depth + 1`, `path = parent.path + hex(id)`, `parent_id = parent.id` (pseudo code) for example:

```
id    path            depth    parent_id    assigned_user_id
------------------------------------------------------------
1     001             0        NULL         NULL
2     002             0        NULL         1
3     001003          1        1            2
4     002004          1        2            1
5     001003005       2        3            2
6     001003005006    3        5            2
7     002004007       2        4            1
8     002004008       2        4            2
9     002004009       2        4            2
10    00200400800A    3        8            2
```

and so on...
The problem is how to get the records for specific user id limited to the shortest path **in the same branch**. For example for `assigned_user_id = 2` retrive:

```
id    path            depth    parent_id    assigned_user_id
------------------------------------------------------------
3     001003          1        1            2
8     002004008       2        4            2
9     002004009       2        4            2
```

Instead of:

```
id    path            depth    parent_id    assigned_user_id
------------------------------------------------------------
3     001003          1        1            2
5     001003005       2        3            2
6     001003005006    3        5            2
8     002004008       2        4            2
9     002004009       2        4            2
10    00200400800A    3        8            2
```

Comment: I don't understand. You write you need the shortest path, yet in your desired output, there are multiple records with different path lengths. Please be more clear on what are your criteria to select the records.

Comment: @Krab The start of the paths should be equal. Thanks for the comment I'll update my question.

Comment: Basically, I think I understand the question. I'd like you to elaborate on this situation. Suppose, the items defined by the paths `001003` and `001003005006` are assigned to user `2`, and `001003005` is assigned to user `1`. Would it be correct to dismiss `001003005006` merely on the grounds that it starts with `001003`? In other words, should the adjacency of the levels (depths) be taken into account?

Comment: My other question is, what type is `path`? (I mean, if it's not `char`/`varchar`.)

Comment: @Andriy The type is `varchar` and answering your first question: **Yes** the dismissal of `001003005006` is correct.

Comment: @veritas: Thanks. I overcomplicated things then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM atable t1
  LEFT JOIN atable t2
    ON t2.assigned_user_id = t1.assigned_user_id AND
       t2.path = LEFT(t1.path, CHAR_LENGTH(t2.path)) AND
       t2.id <> t1.id
WHERE t1.assigned_user_id = 2
  AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: It seems to me it's more optimal solution than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162527/shortest-string-within-same-path-branch/6162874#6162874 (which is also valid)

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, it might be enough to exclude rows whose parent_id is among the ids selected. This is because if the parent and child is selected, they must be in the same branch. The parent's path will be shorter, therefore it's OK to exclude the child.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM x 
  WHERE assigned_user_id = 2 
        AND parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM x WHERE assigned_user_id = 2)
```

If you would have a tree like this (numbers are your assigned user ids):

```
  A1                    G2
 / \                   / \
B2  C2                H2  I2
    | \               |   | \
    D2  E2            L1  J2 K2
                      |
                      M2
```

B2, C2, G2 and M2 would be selected. I'm still not sure if this was your intention, though.

Comment: Had this idea, too, but it doesn't work. Example: Imagine you had a node N2 as child of M2.

Comment: Nice, +1. I was thinking about processing the path string and taking into account the depth level, but your approach looks much simpler. I like it better.

Comment: @Wolfgang: Why, I don't think `N2` would show up with this script.

Comment: @Andriy: So if there was a N2, M2 would still show up in the table? Then it worked, you are right. I thought of something like two rows 001 and 001002003 where the latter had the parent 2 which wasn't in the table. But if 001002003 implies that 001002 is also present then the solution is just fine.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong. It now appears (based on the OP's answer to my question) that M2 shouldn't be in the output in either case. I.e. an item should be displayed, if it has no parents at all with the same user assigned. This solution presently checks the immediate parent only, not all the way up to the root.

Comment: @Wolfgang the appliaction ensures that all tree parts are present, while deleting children are moved or deleted.

Comment: Okay, so the solution is not working because it will select M2 since its parent (L1) has the user id 1 and will not be covered by the inner select. But M2 should not be in the result because G2 is shorter. So there is actually the need for a recursive check which is not possible in SQL. A solution therefore has to use the path column.

Comment: @veritas: If you mean that the application ensures that there can't be a situation where a node and its grandparent are assigned to one user while the parent is assigned to a different user, then this solution should work well for you. Mine is more universal, because it produces the desired output even in the aforementioned case. However, if you don't need that universality, this solution seems more efficient. (Still, I'd verify that to make sure.)

Comment: Missing: `.. OR parent_id IS NULL`. It's not perfect since M2 would be also selected, but +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PATHS WHERE ASSIGNED_USER_ID = 2
AND NOT PARENT_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PATHS WHERE ASSIGNED_USER_ID = 2)
```

Basically the idea is to select top parent nodes for the given user.

Answer (score 1):

Idea behind this: B is shorter than A if A starts with B. Maybe there's something better than LIKE to do this "begins with".

```
SELECT a.* FROM node AS a
WHERE a.assigned_user_id = ?
AND NOT EXIST
(SELECT * FROM node AS b
    WHERE b.assigned_user_id = ?
    AND LENGTH(a.path) > LENGTH(b.path) 
    AND a.path LIKE CONCAT(b.path, '%') )
```

Both ? are mapped to the desired user id.

**EDIT**

Forgot to include the assigned_user_id. Changed the code.

**2nd EDIT**

Changed code to avoid the case of b=a.

Comment: Ouch, you're right. The inner select will also find b=a. I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Working 100% :) But, I'm analyzing every solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select child.assigned_user_id, child.id
from node as child
left join node as parent
on child.path like CONCAT(parent.path, '%')
and child.assigned_user_id = parent.assigned_user_id
and child.id <> parent.id
group by child.assigned_user_id, child.id
having max(parent.id is null) = true
```

(Not sure it'll work exactly as above, but basically: to left join on the path in order to extract the full list of parents, and then to aggregate in such a way that you only keep the nodes without any parents when grouped by assigned_user_id.)